# Include OpenXML assembly when publishing

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, openxml-sdk, webdeploy

I've got an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with a reference to a class library project which is using OpenXML installed via NuGet.

> Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml

[image]

It all works on my development machine. But when I publish the OpenXML assembly (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll) is no where to be found on the server.

What do I need to do get it included when I publish?

Answer (score 0):

You should set **copy to local** to **true** for that assembly file. To do that, right click on the reference file (which is showed in your image) and then click "properties". In the showed window you can find it.

Comment: **copy to local** is set to **true**, I believe the NuGet installer does that

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any instance of `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` from your workstation's Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

1. Open the GAC root in Windows Explorer (Win 7: `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly`)
2. Search for `OpenXml`
3. Delete any appropriate folders (or to be safe, cut them out to your desktop in case you should want to restore them)

Answer (score 0):

remove the dll and add is a nuget: 
`Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml`